# PHP if function

Tags: php, mysql, database, limits

I am using a PHP function to pull some information into a list for me - and it pulls all of it, but the sort is not working and I have messed with the LIMIT and it doesn't work as well...

```
if(strtolower($term) == 'feature') {
    $query = "select * FROM $table WHERE (tags LIKE 'feature') ORDER BY rid DESC     LIMIT 1";
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.  what are you expecting vs what are you actually getting?

Comment: well i want it to order these in descending order and it's not functioning - the order is random actually, and the limit does nothing

Comment: Sorry, what was the question again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are wanting to use some % operators eg these will match anything in your like statement.

Match any tag that has the word feature in it, other letters might be on left and right of word.

```
$query = "select * FROM $table WHERE (tags LIKE '%feature%') ORDER BY rid DESC     LIMIT 1";
```

Match any tag that has that start with feature and may have other words or letters after

```
$query = "select * FROM $table WHERE (tags LIKE 'feature%') ORDER BY rid DESC     LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I knew it had to be something simple... Thank you John.